# NinePatch 9 textbox with one image

Tags: android

I want to implement this image

[image]

## area textview 1 to textview 9 ninepatch able

how can I ninepatch exactly this ??

Comment: As you already seen in your previous related question you can't create a single master nine patch image, you create smaller images and combine them through views.

Comment: give your parent layout background also that 9patch image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not doable with only one 9patch. You must use the following 9patch

[image: parent_element]

to put the borders on your parent.

For the textviews inside your parent element you must use another 9patch for borders and gradients.